# Return value from inner class in a method

Tags: java, android, json, http, callback

I am building a Login system for an Android app. I am using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to connect to my server and get a JSON response.

I have defined a class with the login return data (right now just a true/false response based on whether the user exists in the database), and then written the code to connect to the server, as shown below:

```
class UserLogin {
    boolean status;

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}

public class ClientServerInterface {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    boolean login(Request request) {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            UserLogin login;
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                login = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), UserLogin.class);
                login.setStatus(login.status);
            }
        });
        // need to return the boolean response (status) here
    }
}
```

The code which passes the `Request` variable to the `login` method works perfectly. I want `login` to return a boolean response so that I can pass that to other methods in other classes.

However, because the `UserLogin` object is defined in the `callback` I can't access it in the parent method. I have made a `getStatus` method but not sure how to use it properly to get the status in the main `login` method.

Comment: `// need to return the boolean response (status) here` => obviously you cannot do this ... because when this method returns the request may still be running

Answer (score 2):

> The code which passes the Request variable to the login method works
>   perfectly. I want login to return a boolean response so that I can
>   pass that to other methods in other classes.

you can't. `enqueue` executes the code in Async way. You don't know when the callback is invoked. What you could do is to add the Callback as parameter to your login method. E.g.

```
 boolean login(Request request, final Callback callback) {
```

and either pass it to `enqueue`,

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
```

or call the callback manually. E.g.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
      if (callback != null) {
           callback.onResponse(call, response);
      }
}
```

in both cases the caller of login will receive the callback on the provided object and, accordingly to the content it receives, can decide wha actions undertake

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a `SynchronousQueue`:

```
final SynchronousQueue<Boolean> queue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        UserLogin login;
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
          queue.put(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
          queue.put(true);
        }
    });
return queue.take();
```

Comment: @Selvin that's more of a comment on OP's question/requirement than my answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks the answer. @selvin/Andy, I assume from the answers I'm not doing this quite right. It'd be great if you could suggest better ways to re-write my code so that this works. Essentially I just need to get the `status` variable - if the `login` method doesn't return anything then that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: @TomOakley Selvin is (I think) saying that you should actually have a callback, in order that you can take some action *once the request has completed*. That callback should be passed as a parameter to the `login` method, e.g. `void login(Request request, Callback onRequestComplete) {`

Answer (score 0):

Add loginStatus variable to class like below and one more to indicate login operation completion.

```
public class ClientServerInterface {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private  boolean loginStatus = false;
    private boolean isLoginOperationDone = false;
    boolean login(Request request) {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            UserLogin login;
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                login = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), UserLogin.class);
                loginStatus = login.setStatus(login.status);
                isLoginOperationDone = true;
            }
        });
        // need to return the boolean response (status) here
        while( !isLoginOperationDone )
        {
           //not to do anything.
        }
        return loginStatus;
    }
}
```

Note that this might be a little hacky but will do solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is with AsyncTask. Override the doInBackground method to perform the http requests and get the result by overriding the onPostExecute method.

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

An even better way to go is to run a background Service for all your API calls.

Comment: Excuse me sir, but he is not using an AsyncTask. Also, I'm suggesting to go with a Service instead but I find it to be a bit more work than just a simple AsyncTask.